# How to disable user's password via puppet securely?

Tags: linux, puppet, password, user-management

I have my SSH servers setup to use only Public Key authentication with password authentication disabled.

When adding users through puppet I would like to disable user passwords.

So far I have came up with this, which seems to work, but I am not sure how secure is this:

```
user { 'john':
    ensure     => 'present',
    comment    => 'John Smith',
    groups     => ['adm','sudo','wheel','users'],
    home       => '/home/john',
    managehome => true,
    shell      => '/bin/bash',
    password   => '*',
}
```

Is using `password => '*'` definition considered safe for disabling user password?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [shadow(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/shadow) man pages says

> If the password field contains some string that is not a valid result of crypt(3), for instance ! or *, the user will not be able to use a unix password to log in (but the user may log in the system by other means).

So yes it is safe to use a `*`. The `!` a the first character of an encrypted password is used by [passwd(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/passwd) to indicate that a password is locked (`passwd -l`) and this can be unlocked (`passwd -u`).